# Is it worth concatenating javascript files for a local application (iBooks epub)

Tags: javascript, performance, zepto, ibooks, epub3

I am coding an interactive epub for iBooks using [zepto.js](http://zeptojs.com), plus a few of my own scripts.

As I understand it, it's best practice to combine javascript files for improved performance (as you are reducing http requests to the server).

Is there a performance advantage if your files are local?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, there's no way of benchmarking javascript performance in iBooks; however, I couldn't detect a reduction in performance when loading separate javascript files. And, if anything, performance appeared to get worse when I combined my javascript files.

So, it seems that there is no performance advantage to combining local javascript files in iBooks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to benchmark this quite easily using Readium in conjunction with the Chrome devtools network, profile and/or timeline views. I agree with @ben-manley that there is no meaningful benefit from combining or minifying or zipping JS files, or CSS files for that matter, other than the effect on the size of the EPUB file.